# Selenium test in Java returns the error: Connection reset

Tags: java, selenium

I tried some selenium and it worked but stopped in the middle of the crawling process

these are codes:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class Kream {
   private static WebDriver driver;
   public static final String WEB_DRIVER_ID = "webdriver.chrome.driver";   // 크롬 드라이버
   public static final String WEB_DRIVER_PATH = "C://chromedriver.exe";
   
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Kream krm = new Kream();
      int rank = 0;   // 순서 주려고 선언
      
      System.setProperty(WEB_DRIVER_ID, WEB_DRIVER_PATH);   // 운영체제 드라이버 설정
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();   // 옵션 쓰려고 객체화
      options.addArguments("headless");
      options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
      
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
      
      try {
         String url = "https://kream.co.kr/search?category_id=34&sort=popular&per_page=40";
         driver.get(url);
         
         List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.className("search_result_item"));

         var stTime = new Date().getTime(); //현재시간
           
         while (new Date().getTime() < stTime + 15000) { //30초 동안 무한스크롤 지속
               Thread.sleep(500); //리소스 초과 방지
               //executeScript: 해당 페이지에 JavaScript 명령을 보내는 거
               ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)", el);

            for (WebElement element:el) {
               System.out.println(++rank+". ");
               System.out.print(element.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("src"));
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("brand")).getText());         
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("name")).getText());
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("translated_name")).getText());
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("amount")).getText());
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("desc")).getText());
               System.out.print("|"+element.findElement(By.className("express_mark")).getText());
               System.out.println();
               
            }
      
         }
           
      } finally {
         driver.close();
         driver.quit();
      }
   }

}
```

and return the error that says

```
onError


java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

current versions:
chromedriver version:103.0.5060.24
chrome version: 103.0.5060.114

I already tried to match the both versions so mismatching wouldn't be the reason probably.

Thank you for the answer in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made changes to your script and this was working fine as expected, please check the below!
If still you encountered any issues, kindly share complete logs for issue resolution.

```
package com.selenium;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.PageLoadStrategy;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

public class Kream {

  private static WebDriver driver;
  public static final String WEB_DRIVER_ID = "webdriver.chrome.driver";   // 크롬 드라이버
  public static final String WEB_DRIVER_PATH = "C://chromedriver.exe";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Kream krm = new Kream();
    int rank = 0;   // 순서 주려고 선언

    System.setProperty(WEB_DRIVER_ID, WEB_DRIVER_PATH);   // 운영체제 드라이버 설정
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();   // 옵션 쓰려고 객체화
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    try {
      String url = "https://kream.co.kr/search?category_id=34&sort=popular&per_page=40";
      driver.get(url);

      List<WebElement> el = driver.findElements(By.className("search_result_item"));

      var stTime = new Date().getTime(); //현재시간

      while (new Date().getTime() < stTime + 15000) { //30초 동안 무한스크롤 지속
        Thread.sleep(500); //리소스 초과 방지
        //executeScript: 해당 페이지에 JavaScript 명령을 보내는 거
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
            .executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)", el);

        for (WebElement element : el) {
          System.out.println(++rank + ". ");
          System.out.print(element.findElement(By.tagName("img")).getAttribute("src"));
          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("brand")).getText());
          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("name")).getText());
          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("translated_name")).getText());
          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("amount")).getText());
          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("desc")).getText());
//          System.out.print("|" + element.findElement(By.className("express_mark")).getText());
          /*The above tag with class name as express_mark doesn't have any text attribute and hence, this is commented out!*/
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
    } finally {
      driver.close();
      driver.quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sure this answered the OP.  but for others who face similar issues this is not a great answer. an explanation of what was changed and why it works now would be great